# Application terminates before onStop() is finished

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-lifecycle

I have a logic in my application so that when OnStop() happens I save a file to the storage. However, if the file is large and I close application by swiping from Recents Tab my application is shut down before my file is saved. So it opens file then app dies and the file remains empty.
Is that normal behaviour or the task killer on my phone is overplaying? Should I create a service to save a file certainly?

example code:

```java
@Override
public void onStop() {
  try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path)) {
    if (veryLargeFile == null) { 
      return;
    }
    String s = veryLargeFile.toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "this message is shown");
    writer.write(s);
    Log.d(TAG, "this message is not shown");
    writer.flush();
  } catch (IOException ex) {}
  super.onStop();
}
```

Example 2:

```java
@Override
public void onPause() {
  try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path)) {
    if (veryLargeFile == null) { 
      return;
    }
    String s = veryLargeFile.toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "this message is shown");
    writer.write(s);
    Log.d(TAG, "this message is not shown");
    writer.flush();
  } catch (Exception ex) {    
    Log.d(TAG, "this message is not shown");
  }
  super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: If I put my saving code in onPause() the same behavior

Comment: Yes foreground can solve your problem

Comment: Use a WorkManager, works in background and can to save the file with the app killed

Comment: either work manager or a forground service would help in this situaton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes sense, I presume the file save will happen asynchronously so you have no guarantee that it will finish before the application is torn down completely.

As some people in the comments have already pointed out, `WorkManager` is probably your best solution here and is able to defer asynchronous tasks for the system to manage, so will be able to run even if your app finishes.

There is some nice documentation here: [Schedule tasks with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

---

**Edit**

If the code you're trying to run is synchronous, it should still be able to complete during `onStop` (post Honeycomb) or `onPause` due to the lifecycle methods being (as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle) describes it)  "unkillable".

However this is still no guarantee if your app is force stopped or crashes whilst finishing and as the lifecycle documentation states:

> Keep in mind that under extreme memory pressure the system can kill the application process at any time.

So I would presume that this is an issue with the memory management on your specific device which causes the app to be killed prematurely. If this is the case then I would consider using a better persisting method, either on a regular interval or during your apps foreground time if it is essential.

Comment: Can you please explain why my app is torn down in the middle of my code? I have FileWriter and the app terminates in write() method. I don't know if it is asynchronous but after that I have flush() which is not reached

Comment: That's interesting, `FileWriter` runs on the main thread as far as I am aware, let me do some more research and get back to you!

Comment: The problem remains regardless of whether I do file write in `onStop()` or in `onPause()`

Comment: Are you checking whether it throws an exception?

Comment: @gamarjoba, _"Can you please explain why my app is torn down in the middle of my code?"_ It is how the system acts. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34463069/3290339) I answered a question that asked a very similar thing.

Comment: I don't know if I think this is correct, if you look here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle is says that `onStop` is not killable, apart from in the event of a crash etc.

Comment: Added one more example. According to the link above, onPause is not killable so I can take my time to save my large file in storage, right? But in my case when I swipe away my app from recents the app dies before onPause is finished. Did I misinterpret killable section in documentation or my something wrong with my task killer?

Comment: Edited my answer, I think the theory points towards your implementation being fine, but your device still can end the task whenever it needs to reclaim memory, so I think this is just an edge case

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59128513/10146467) here is said that the app cannot die until onStop is returned, but in my case it does.

Comment: That is the theory, but as it says in the documentation I linked - "Keep in mind that under extreme memory pressure the system can kill the application process at any time."